# Using MessageReceiver only first time getting message from topic using Azure Function HttpTrigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Using `MessageReceiver` only first time getting messages from topic using Azure Function after that next time when execute Function though I have messages into `service bus topic` still getting null into variable `messages`.

Using below code to get messages from Service Bus Topic , whats the cause?

```
string serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("topicName/subscriptions/subscriptionName"), ReceiveMode.PeekLock, null, 500);

var messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

> i can't understand this - after every 15 minutes when LA call FA then
>   FA should able to read new available messages but it is coming null

[image]

is there anything related with lock duration ?

Comment: Why are you not using Service Bus Triggers when you already use Azure Functions? Thats exactly what they are for. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus

Comment: because my use-case is different i'm calling this http trigger FA from Logic app.

Comment: Have you tried your function code outside of the function? Also, I would verify the settings are pointing to the correct environment.

Comment: yup settings are also correct .. not sure why this kind of behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
var messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

will wait until it receives one or more messages and will then return. Any messages that come in later will not be read. If you want to do that (and I want to doubt that this is a good idea inside an Azure Function), put this in a loop:

```
while(/* some condition */)
{
     messages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
     // do something with the received messages
}
```

Comment: this http trigger based azure function will get called from logic app after every 15 minutes so if we have any new messages after 15 minutes i'm reading those and make it complete after processing.
how to tackle this situation ?

Comment: I cannot really tell, what you are actually trying to achieve. You can also have a timer-triggered Azure Function if you really want to only ready new messages every 15minutes.

Comment: i can't understand this - after every 15 minutes when LA call FA then FA should able to read new available messages ?

Comment: well yeah, this does technically work. I'm just questioning if this is a great idea.

Comment: I want to use those message data into my Logic app to process so that is why i'm doing like this is

Comment: why aren't you then just using a Service Bus triggered Logic App? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus#add-service-bus-trigger

Comment: because logic app is trigger based on timmer and inside that on some condition executing HTTP function app

Answer (score 1):

If i didn't understand it wrong, you use a timer trigger logic app to call the function to get the service bus message and you always get the old message and you don't want it.

You always get the old message because your ReceiveMode is PeekLock, about this ReceiveMode  you could check this description:[Receive mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#receive-mode). After `complete` the message, the message wouldn't be deleted, that's why you always get the old message.

First way is you could change it to `ReceiveAndDelete` when you create `MessageReceiver` like the below code.

```
            string serviceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("servicebuscon");
            var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, "myqueue", ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete, null, 500);


            var tempMessages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Note: if your function go exception or other errors and the message doesn't get processed completely, this message will be deleted with this mode.

The other way is after process the message call the [CompleteAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.core.messagereceiver.completeasync?view=azure-dotnet) method, after process the message will be deleted.

You could refer to the below code.

```
            var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(serviceBusConnectionString, "myqueue", ReceiveMode.PeekLock, null, 500);

            var tempMessages = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(500, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            foreach (Message m1 in tempMessages)
            {

                log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function processed message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m1.Body)}");
                await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(m1.SystemProperties.LockToken);

            }
```

Comment: exactly i used the 2nd given approach :) my issue is i'm not getting old message i'm getting null into messages though i have messages into topic :(

Comment: If you complete the message it will be deleted .

Comment: yes it is deleted but next time i have new messages coming into that topic i should get those New messages as every 15 minutes my FA is running this same code

Comment: you should get available new messages every time when FA is running right ?

Comment: is there anything related with lock duration ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Batch Operation should be false.

But this is also working for random times - not a reliable solution for the problem.

Check the below screenshot:

[image]